# I lost my sd card for Raspberry Pi 3 model B V 1.2

Tags: sd-card

I had lost my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V 1.2 2015 SD card can I download some files on to a new SD card?

Comment: `download some files` ... what files are you talking about?

Comment: Can you download files to an SD card?  Sure!  Perhaps you meant something specific, like the PI operating system... which there are several versions of if you bother to look around at all.

Comment: How do you think that the SD card that you bought got it's OS on it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel the question should not have been asked without any investment of the OP's time or effort. [This help topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states: `"Asking for references to online material"`. The question is also at odds with several points in [this help topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Flash the latest Raspberry Pi OS to a micro sd card using Pi Imager.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/